# how to quit nodejs debug mode quit

Tags: node.js, debugging

Normally i can quit node app by press `ctrl + c`, however during debug mode, if i continue press `c` which is

> c => continue with code execution

however by the end of the execution, i couldn't exit, i tried press `q` and `ctrl+c`, please find the screenshot below, it just stuck there. This can be annoying during debugging...

wondering if i am doing incorrectly or there is another shortcut or hotkey to quit.

[image]

nodejs 5.5.0

Answer (score 9):

In order to quit the debug mode you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> twice. Alternatively you can type `.exit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: yeah that's works in between, but if you keep hitting c eventually it will stuck and ctrl+c won't work for some reason